# Internal and external cluster communication in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: neo4j, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I building a Kubernetes cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). It is basically a `Service` with an associated `ReplicaSet` with a number of pods.

Those pods need to talk to each other for keeping consensus. For this end, a `ClusterIP` seems a good fit, allowing intra cluster communication of the pods.

However, now I want to expose this Service to the world. My idea was to switch from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort` and couple it with an `Ingress`, which seems to be the [best practice](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#background).

My problem is that when I switch the `Service` to `NodePort`, I lose the internal communication of the cluster, i.e. pods can't talk to each other. As far as my understanding goes, `NodePort` [is a superset of `ClusterIP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41510604/4766124), so it should keep internal communication.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit with extra information:

I am referring to [this example](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/kubernetes-neo4j), an example of a Neo4j graph database.

The example deploys a `StatefulSet`, in which pods need to communicate, among other things, for keeping consensus between the cluster.

With the provided setting, pods can talk to each other. If I change the [Service](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/kubernetes-neo4j/blob/master/cores/dns.yaml) to `NodePort`, and fix the `nodePorts` that are used (instead of choosing them randomly as it normally does), pods can no longer communicate.

Is this expected behavior, or am I missing something?

Comment: That must be a GKE-specific bug, because I am 100% positive NodePort and ClusterIP coexist, since easily 80% of our Pods in our cluster use the ClusterIP to speak to other Services (and a great deal of our Services are NodePort exactly for the Ingress reason you mentioned). Now what I _can't_ say with 100% certainty is whether they can speak to _each other_ that way.

Comment: Can you expand on what "lose the internal communication" looks like in practice? DNS failure, TCP rejection, TCP timeout, X out of Y connections fail, ... that kind of thing

Comment: I added the example in the question. Losing internal communication means that pods, they stay forever in the following state:


`2017-09-13 09:39:59.977+0000 INFO  Attempting to connect to the other cluster members before continuing...`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `NodePort` is a superset of `ClusterIP`, but to be clear, you do not need the service to be of `NodePort` type for it to be exposed by IngressController. IC has access to endpoints (pods) directly, so there is no need to use anything but `ClusterIP`.

Another thing is that ClusterIP service has no effect on pod-to-pod connectivity, and also it seems a bit weird that you would use service to allow consensus chatter (unless you have an svc per pod). For this kind of operations you might want to look closer at the [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) concept

Comment: As far as I know, in GKE, you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37514073/4766124) expose a `ClusterIP` with an Ingress, but I'm not 100% sure.